# Read JSON with Jersey 2.0 (JAX-RS 2.0)

Tags: json, jax-rs, java-ee-7, jersey-client, jersey-2.0

I was using `Jersey 1.16` to consume a `JSON`, but now I'm with difficulties to consume a JSON using Jersey 2.0 (that implements JAX-RS 2.0).

I have a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "id": 105430,
    "version": 0,
    "cpf": "55443946447",
    "email": "maria@teste.br",
    "name": "Maria",
}
```

and the method that consumes it:

```java
public static JSONObject get() {
   String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/core/api/person";
   URI uri = URI.create(url);

   final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
   WebTarget webTarget = client.target(uri);            

   Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

   if (response.getStatus() == 200) {      
      return response.readEntity(JSONObject.class);
   }
}
```

I also tried:

```java
return webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(JSONObject.class);
```

But the **jSONObject return is null**. I don't understand my error because the response is OK!

Comment: Can you tell more about what is `JSONObject`? What if you change the return type to `String`? Because, using `String`, you should get the payload. If not, you have to check your url. If the url is correct, then you have a server side issue. Now, if the payload is the expected JSON, then your problem is not having a `MessageBodyReader` that supports your `JSONObject`.

Comment: JSONObject is a class of [Jettison API] (http://jettison.codehaus.org/). It is a collection of key/value pairs [Docs] (http://jettison.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONObject.html). Using JSONObject, I can get the value with the get() method.

Comment: The URL is correct, because the status is OK (200 - The request has succeeded).

Comment: Acknowledged, it is status 200. But about the content, got the expected JSON? And the content-type is application/json, right?

Comment: Yes, the content is JSON.
`System.out.println("S: " + webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));` => OK
`System.out.println("J: " + webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(JSONObject.class).toString());` => error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to use the Response type correctly:

```
  private void getRequest() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    String url = "http://localhost:8080/api/masterdataattributes";
    WebTarget target = client.target(url);

    Response res = target
        .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .get();

    int status = res.getStatus();
    String json = res.readEntity(String.class);

    System.out.println(String.format("Status: %d, JSON Payload: %s", status, json));
  }
```

If you're just interested in the payload, you could also just issue a get(String.class). But usually you will also want to check the response status, so working with the Response is usually the way to go.

If you want a typed (generic) JSON response, you could also have readEntity return a Map, or a list of Map if the response is an array of objects as in this example:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> json = res.readEntity(new GenericType<List<Map<String, Object>>>() {});
String id = (String) json.get(0).get("id");
System.out.println(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution. Maybe it is not the best of, but it works.

```java
public static JsonObject get() {
  String url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/core/api/person";
  URI uri = URI.create(url);

  final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
  WebTarget webTarget = client.target(uri);

  Response response = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();

  //Se Response.Status.OK;
  if (response.getStatus() == 200) {
     StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(String.class));
     try (JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(stringReader)) {
        return jsonReader.readObject();
     }
  }

  return null;
```

}

I switched the class JSONObject (package import org.codehaus.jettison) by JsonObject (package javax.json) and I used the methods to manipulate the content as String.

S.

Comment: After you get the string, you can also use `new JsonObject(string)`.

Comment: But JsonObject is a interface. To use it I need implement all methods.

Comment: What? No, you said it was from [Jettison](http://jettison.codehaus.org/apidocs/org/codehaus/jettison/json/JSONObject.html), a concrete class. If the documentation isn't wrong, then your interface is not the Jettison class.

Comment: Hum, I thought that you were commenting about package javax.json.JsonObject. Look, the JsonObject interface is different of the JSONObject class. =)

Comment: Yes, I see, I said `JsonObject` when I was talking about `JSONObject`. Please forgive my mistake.

Comment: This is certainly not how it should be done! You're calling get() twice, one time for the status, one time for the payload. This also results in two HTTP requests! I'll post an answer below of how to do it correctly with one request...

Answer (score 1):

**mmey** answer is the correct and optimal one, instead of invoking the service twice it does it one time.